# how to change background using render.py in CGKIT

Tags: python, cgkit

i am working with CGKIT in my project, i came across a situation that i must use only render.py file and change the background of the picture.
i know how to use viewer.py and change the picture but implementing that i.e. changing background in GLOBALS it is not changing the background as per render.py
so please any one help me out

```
# Use the previously rendered texture map
from time import sleep
import Image
from cgkit.cgtypes import vec3, mat4
from cgkit.cmds import load, worldObject
from cgkit.glmaterial import GLMaterial, GLTexture
from cgkit.scene import getScene
from cgkit.sceneglobals import Globals
from OpenGL.GL import glReadPixels
from pyglet.gl import GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_DECAL

Globals(
    resolution=(512,512),
    up = (0,1,0),
    background=(1,1,1,1),
    output = "kishoreGoodBoy.png",
)

load("singleSofa.obj")
model = worldObject("small_sofa_dark_grey")

mat = GLMaterial(
    diffuse = (0,1,0),
    texture = GLTexture(
        "final1.png",
        mode = GL_DECAL,
        transform = mat4().scaling(vec3(1,-1,1))
    )
)
model.setMaterial(mat)
```

as per code i had textre file and so that i am directing it to a .PNG file and it is saving. but it is coming with a black background so i need to change the background clour

Comment: could you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: @Dannnno: i had editted the question plz refer to it

Comment: What has this to do with django?